# Hiding or Showing a paticular form based on the dropdown selection in MVC and Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

When I choose Adjustment on the dropdown I am able to get Value, but when rendering the correct form the Dropdown UI in the form does not have the correct Value. It almost works, but I feel I am not doing the jquery correctly.  In the View I have 2 different forms, I use the Jquery to select which form I want to show based on the Dropdown Selection.

HERES THE JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#adjustments").hide();
        $(".TypeClass").change(function() {
            var selected = $(".TypeClass option:selected").text();
            alert(selected);
            if (selected == "Received") {
                $("#received").show();
                $("#adjustments").hide();
            }
            if (selected == "Adjustment") {
                $("#adjustments").show();
                $("#received").hide();
            }
        });


        $(".TypeClass2").change(function() {
            var selected = $(".TypeClass2 option:selected").text();
            alert(selected);
            if (selected == "Received") {
                $("#received").show();
                $("#adjustments").hide();
                               }
            if (selected == "Adjustment") {
                $("#adjustments").show();
                $("#received").hide();
                              }

        });
    });
```

HERES THE VIEW

```
<div id="received">
   <fieldset>
   <legend>New Inventory Transaction</legend>
    <table>
       <tr><td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemName)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemName)</td></tr>
       <tr><td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemNumber)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemNumber)</td></tr>
       <tr><td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.XactTypeId)</td><td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.XactTypeId, (SelectList)ViewData["InvType"], "Choose Type", new { @class = "TypeClass" })</td></tr>   
       <tr><td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.XactTotalCost)</td><td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.XactTotalCost)</td></tr>
       <tr><td></td><td><p> <input type="submit" value="Create" /></p></td></tr>     
       </table>   
       </fieldset>
       </div>    
        <div id="adjustments">
       <fieldset>
       <legend>New Inventory Transaction</legend>   
       <table>
       <tr><td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemName)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemName)</td></tr>
       <tr><td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemNumber)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemNumber)</td></tr>
        <tr><td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.WharehouseName)</td><td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WharehouseName)</td></tr>     
       <tr><td></td><td><p> <input type="submit" value="Create" /></p></td></tr>   

       </table>

       </fieldset>
       </div>
```

Comment: In the UI portion when I test it out, the dropdownlist is not matching the ALERTS that I have set up. Is there some jquery that will allow me set it Like this in C#  dropdownlist1.SelectedValue = "myValue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to set a drop down list value just use
    $("ddl").val("your val");
and to get the selected value usev
    var selectedval = $("ddl").val();

Answer (score 0):

Drop Down

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AttendenceBonus.BonusIn, new SelectList(Model.BonusInList, "Value", "Text", Model.AttendenceBonus.BonusIn), new { @class = "selectBoxRegular", onchange = "return GetBonusType(this);"})
```

Script

```
<script>
    function GetBonusType(ctrl) {

       var x = $("#AttendenceBonus_BonusIn").val();

       // hide any control by id

            if (x == "Fixed") {
                $('#persent').text("");
                $('#Applylevel').show();
                $('#AttendenceBonus_BonusApplyOn').show();
            }

         // Show any control by id
           else {
               $('#persent').text("%");
               $('#Applylevel').hide();
               $('#AttendenceBonus_BonusApplyOn').hide();
            }
     }

</script>
```

[You can also see the GIF](http://atikpassion.blogspot.com/2014/01/mvc-razor-show-hide-any-id-based-on.html)